# How can I get file type and created date/time using gem 'google_drive' in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-drive-api

I'm developing a Rails application that gets the file under specific folder in Google Drive using the following gems:

```
gem 'google_drive'
gem 'google-api-client', '0.9'
gem 'googleauth'
```

From this repository [github](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby).

My problem is that the **returned result** contains **ONLY**

```
* filename
* file id
```

My code looks like:

```
result = []

response = @service.list_files(
  q: "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'xxxx' in parents",
  order_by: 'createdTime desc',
  spaces: 'drive',
  fields:'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
)

response.files.each do |file|
  result << file
end
```

I want to get the **file's type and dateTime created or uploaded**.

I need the **created/uploaded dateTime for display purposes**

while the mime type is for me to get the [Supported Mime Type](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types) as I will use for **querying in API.**

And also, I want to make sure if this is the **easy and best way to download a file from browser** (**client side**), since I already got the **fileID**:

```
<a href="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<%= file_id] %>?alt=media">
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation regarding the migration of Google Drive v2 to v3? based from the document, all `date/time` fields are now suffixed with `Time` instead of `Date`. The Children and Parents collections have been removed. Use files.list instead. You may check the method, parameters and fields here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

For getting the **uploadedDateTime** & **mimeType** of each file:

I added additional options in **fields:**

```
response = @service.list_files(
      q: "'yyyyy' in parents",
      order_by: 'createdTime desc, modifiedTime desc, name',
      spaces: 'drive',
      fields:'nextPageToken, files(id, name, createdTime, mimeType)',
      page_size: 20
    )
```

Thanks to suggestion of @d.datul1990

But, for this:

```
The Children and Parents collections have been removed. Use files.list instead.
```

I don't need to update the current code since I'm using **ruby gems** (gem 'google_drive') that has its own function.

**And for downloading file in browser:** (**Note**: files are not for public, ONLY loggedIn user to company email can download.)

Since I already have the **file_id**, I did like:

```
<a href="https://drive.google.com/a/xxx.net/file/d/file_id_here/view?usp=sharing" target="_blank">Click to Open/Download</a>
```

> Hope it helps others.